# Stretch jMonkey texture without anti-aliasing/blurring

Tags: java, textures, jmonkeyengine, antialiasing

In JME3, when a texture is loaded from an image, it stretches it to the size of the quad I put it on. But it also blurs it, and I don't want this (I'm making Minecraft style graphics), so how can I stop it?

Also, I think it might have to do something with com.jme3.texture.Texture.MinFilter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I found the answer. You want to set the texture's MagFilter to `Texture.MagFilter.Nearest`; by default its `Texture.MagFilter.Bilinear` and that's what's causing the blurring. Cool.